# Xamarin Forms: Not able to pass the command parameter value from XAML to ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
ICommand _navigateAddNewAddress;
    public ICommand NavigateAddNewAddress => _navigateAddNewAddress ?? (_navigateAddNewAddress = new Command(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            App.PushPage(AppPage.PROFILE_ADD_NEW_RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            App.LogError(ex);
        }
    }));
```

The above code works fine, when I have a command event attached in the XAML without any parameters.

XAML:

```
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding NavigateAddNewAddress}" ></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

Could one please let me know what should be done in the c# code, to access the command parameter value as below,

```
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding NavigateAddNewAddress}" CommandParameter={Binding CurrentAddress}></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

Need to know, how to create the command object which accepts the command parameter value. The below code with "args" parameter is not coming up with the value,It gives me the compilation error.

```
ICommand _navigateAddNewAddress;
    public ICommand NavigateAddNewAddress => _navigateAddNewAddress ?? (_navigateAddNewAddress = new Command(async (sender, args) =>
    {
        try
        {
            App.PushPage(AppPage.PROFILE_ADD_NEW_RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            App.LogError(ex);
        }
    }));
```

Please let me know how to pass the command parameter value directly from XAML to ViewModel

Comment: You can try this 
`<Label.GestureRecognizers>
 <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.NavigateAddNewAddress, Source={x:Reference ContactView}}"
 CommandParameter={Binding CurrentAddress}></TapGestureRecognizer>
</Label.GestureRecognizers>`, give name to content page

`<ContentPage  
 x:Name="ContactView">`

Comment: The event is getting binded to the view model...... Needed to know how to pass the event with parameter

Comment: You can do like this `new Command<string> (CalculateSquareRoot);`  `void CalculateSquareRoot (string value)`